# Multiple drag & drop buttons and target DIVs with HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a couple of buttons, which stand for available webservices in form of maps or graphs. The user would be able to drag the buttons in different DIVs of various sizes on the screen, in order to compose for himself a context on the GUI which fits his needs.

I am not very familiar with the drag-and-drop functionalities of HTML5 and jQuery. I have set up an example, which works fine for a single button and single DIV. But working with multiple buttons and multiple DIVs, I wonder if that workflow of mine is the right one.

I have set up a [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/resfnqwu/2/). The first button can be dragged to the first DIV, and an image (just a placeholder) appears. The others don't work yet.

As the DIVs and Buttons are called by IDs, I could now just have four different IDs for the buttons and four different IDs for the DIVs. But that would that mean that I have to write four times the same javascript code, with the different IDs hard-coded into it? I guess there is a more flexible solution to this, no? Especially, as the target DIVs must stay flexible...

I wonder too how I can avoid of having the button disappear, once it is being dragged. I would rather want to make it grey or so.

Thanks for any hints!

The GUI would look like this:
[image]

For the buttons, I have this:

```
    <div id="a-draggable-div" draggable="true" ondragend="onDragEnd(event)" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" style="float: left">
      <h4 style="float: left">Map :: Precipitation</h4>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
      <h4 style="float: left">Map :: Temperature</h4>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
      <h4 style="float: left">Graph :: Precipitation</h4>
    </div>
    <div style="">
      <h4 style="float: left">Graph :: Temperature</h4>
    </div>

    <br clear="all" />

    <div id="dropzone1" class="static" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondragleave="onDragLeave(event)"></div>
    <div id="dropzone2" class="static" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondragleave="onDragLeave(event)"></div>
    <div id="dropzone3" class="static" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondragleave="onDragLeave(event)"></div>
```

For the javascript part:

```
    function onDragOver(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.className = "over-me";
    }

    function onDragLeave(e) {
      e.target.className = "static";
    }

    function onDragStart(e) {
      e.target.innerHTML = "<h4>You are Dragging me</h4>";
      document.getElementById('dropzone1').className = 'drop-into-me'
    }

    function onDragEnd(e) {
      e.target.innerHTML = "<h4>Drag Me into the Box :)</h4>";
      document.getElementById('dropzone1').className = 'static'
      if (e.target.parentElement.id === "dropzone1") {
        e.target.innerHTML = "<img src='http://ede.grid.unep.ch/images/logo_geo.gif'>";
      }
    }

    function onDrop(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var draggableDiv = document.getElementById("a-draggable-div");
      draggableDiv.setAttribute("draggable", "false");
      e.target.appendChild(draggableDiv);
    }
```

For the CSS:

```
    #dropzone1, #dropzone2, #dropzone3 {
      width: 350px;
      height: 70px;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .static {
      border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }

    .drop-into-me {
      border: 1px dotted #aaaaaa;
    }

    .over-me {
      background-color: yellow;
      border: 1px dotted #aaaaaa;
    }

    h4 {
      background-color: #44c767;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid #18ab29;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 7px 31px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 6px #0e2b0a;
      margin-right: 20px
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can look in jQueryUI ( Draggable and Sortable module ) https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for which you need not to use `id` You can have as many number of buttons and corresponding number of divs to drop in.

Have given `ids` to divs where you will be dropping the buttons just to show in which div the button have been dropped in.

Here is the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/resfnqwu/6/)**.

```js
  

 //just to know which button is being dragged we will use this variable
var draggingDiv;
function onDragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add("over-me");
}

function onDragLeave(e) {
  e.target.classList.add("static");
  e.target.classList.remove("over-me");
}

function onDragStart(e) {
 draggingDiv=e.target;
  e.target.innerHTML = "<h4>You are Dragging me</h4>";
}

function onDragEnd(e) {
 
  e.target.innerHTML = "<h4>Drag Me into the Box :)</h4>";
  e.target.parentElement.classList.add("static");
  draggingDiv.innerHTML="<h4>Dragged once Can't drag me now:)</h4>";
 // e.target.innerHTML = "<h4>You Dropped Me In "+e.target.parentElement.id+"</h4>"; 
}

function onDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.remove("over-me");
  //uncommment the below line if want that the button should not be draggable once it has been dropped in a div already
  //draggingDiv.draggable=false;
   //e.target.appendChild(draggingDiv);/commented as this will take the button to the div but we want it to at the original pposition
  e.target.innerHTML="<span>Please Change My innerHTML or call some function that loads data That handles the graph/map creation in this Div</span>";
  
}
```

```css
.dropzone {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.static {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.drop-into-me {
  border: 1px dotted #aaaaaa;
}

.over-me {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px dotted #aaaaaa;
}

h4 {
  background-color: #44c767;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #18ab29;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 7px 31px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 6px #0e2b0a;
  margin-right: 20px
}
```

```html
<div  draggable="true" ondragend="onDragEnd(event)" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" style="float: left">
  <h4 style="float: left">Map :: Precipitation</h4>
</div>
<div style="float: left" draggable="true" ondragend="onDragEnd(event)" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)">
  <h4 style="float: left">Map :: Temperature</h4>
</div>
<div style="float: left" draggable="true" ondragend="onDragEnd(event)" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)">
  <h4 style="float: left">Graph :: Precipitation</h4>
</div>
<div style="float: left" draggable="true" ondragend="onDragEnd(event)" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)">
  <h4 style="float: left">Graph :: Temperature</h4>
</div>

<br clear="all" />

<div  id="dropzone1" class="static dropzone" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondragleave="onDragLeave(event)"></div>
<div id="dropzone2" class="static dropzone" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondragleave="onDragLeave(event)"></div>
<div id="dropzone3" class="static dropzone" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondragleave="onDragLeave(event)"></div>
<div id="dropzone4" class="static dropzone" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondragleave="onDragLeave(event)"></div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Indeed, that helps a lot. Great. Thanks so much! -- Any idea on how I can drag&drop the button, but then make it stay, in inactive mode, where it was before in the menu bar?

Comment: so you want it to be at both the places i.e in the dropped div as well as at its original location?

Comment: the button being dropped into a DIV will be "transformed" into or replacedby a webservice, that is, a map or a graph. So, the button won't stay in the DIV, which is why it will kept in the menu bar.

Comment: ok so basically what you want is that. When you drop a button into the div. The button should go back to its original position and the div to which the button was dropped should display a graph or a map based on the button dropped into it. Correct me if i'm wrong?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I want. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @luftikus143 have updated the code as well as the fiddle. Please have a look and let me know if any issue. If it solves your problem dont forget to upvote and mark as answer. :)

Comment: Wow, so great. Thanks so much!

Comment: The drag&drop doesn't work in Firefox52.0.1/Mac. Could you check? In Chrome, it doesn't really work properly neither, at last in my [current version](http://npp.grid.unep.ch). Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: add this line as the first statement in `onDragStart` function `e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');` it will work. Let me know if you face any issues

Comment: Cool! Thanks so much!